# Database design : avoid redundancy with a one to many relationship

Tags: database, database-design

I have two tables : Cateogy and Product

```
Category : id (autoincrement), label
Product : id (autoincrement), label, image (blob), category_id(foreign key)
```

So following that design, every time I add a category to a product, that means that the product in somehow duplicated but the only value that will change is the "category_id". I really find it redundant :

```
------------------
| Category       |
-----------------------
| id | label          |
-----------------------
| 1  | entertainment  |
| 2  | professional   |
| 3  | kitchen        |
-----------------------

------------------------------------------
| Product                                |
------------------------------------------
| id | label     | image | category_id   |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | computer  | [BLOB]| 1             |
| 2  | computer  | [BLOB]| 2             |
| 3  | TV        | [BLOB]| 1             |
------------------------------------------
```

**Question** : is there a way to get rid of redundancy from the `product` table  and avoid to duplicate the product so that I can add a category ?

Regards

Comment: Hi. Time to read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design. This is addressed by "normalization". PS This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove Category column from Product table.
2. Create a new table called “Product Categories” with columns: product ID (foreign), category ID (foreign)

Answer (score 2):

The structure that you have literally says that each product can be of one category.  So there is just no question of "adding a category to a product".  If it is the case that "adding a category to a product" is a requirement (meaning it must be possible for a product to have/be associated with/... >1 category) then the database structure is simply wrong and must be revised.